# Multiple Nested Group Within Array in MongoDB using laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

Please refer this question which was posted by my friend.

[Multiple Nested Group Within Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631240/multiple-nested-group-within-array)

Here chridam has given a good answer but we have to implement in laravel php framwork.